# How to assign the index of the last change in a column to each row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame containing a column that is mostly 0, and occasionally some other integer:

```
In[160]: df.tail(10)
Out[160]: 
       alert   value
525590     0  46.374
525591     0  46.303
525592     3  46.310
525593     0  46.300
525594     0  46.400
525595     3  46.300
525596     0  46.310
525597     1  46.303
525598     0  46.387
525599     0  46.400
```

I would like to add a new column that contains the index of the last non-zero value in that column:

```
In[160]: ???.tail(10)
Out[160]: 
       alert   value  change
525590     0  46.374  525585
525591     0  46.303  525585
525592     3  46.310  525592
525593     0  46.300  525592
525594     0  46.400  525592
525595     3  46.300  525595
525596     0  46.310  525595
525597     1  46.303  525597
525598     0  46.387  525597
525599     0  46.400  525597
```

I know how I might do it with an explicit loop, but I was wondering if there was a more pandas-like way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

```
g = df.alert.ne(0)
df.loc[g[g].index, 'change'] = g[g].index
df.ffill()

        alert   value   change
525590  0       46.374  NaN
525591  0       46.303  NaN
525592  3       46.310  525592.0
525593  0       46.300  525592.0
525594  0       46.400  525592.0
525595  3       46.300  525595.0
525596  0       46.310  525595.0
525597  1       46.303  525597.0
525598  0       46.387  525597.0
525599  0       46.400  525597.0
```

Notice that the `NaN` values rose because I just used the last 10 items. Should be fine when running the whole dataset